# laravel login with remember me feature without field in the database

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a website using Laravel with an existing database.
My User table doesn't have a remember me field. But I want users always login with remember me feature. Can anyone help?

Comment: share user's table structure ?

Comment: 'Remember me' functionality doesn't need a database field. Show some code of what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

"Remember me" functionality NEEDS a field in DB. Actually you have to store the "remember me" cookie somewhere in your program. Where is a better place than DB to do this??

First you have to add `remember_token` (100-character string) to your Users table in database which will be used to store the "remember me" token.

In the next step, On your login attemp you must add `$remember` parameter like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

after this code, your user will be remembered by his remember cookie. SO he can be remembered like this:

```
if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
    //
}
```

Anyway, if you want to store the remember_token in another table, you have define a model like `RememberToken` and add this relationship to your `Users` model:

```
public function rememberToken() {
    return $this->hasOne('RememberToken'); // also add foreign keys
}
```

And now some overriding is needed!. First override `getRememberToken()` and `setRememberToken()` methods and also you need to override `getRememberTokenName()`.

As a result `EloquentUserProvider::retrieveByToken()` should be changed in `EloquentUserProvider` class. You probably have to make your `User` model to join `remember_tokens` table on every query by adding global scope to it, and return 'remember_tokens.token' from `getRememberTokenName()` method.

Is it really necessary by the way?

Comment: Thanks.But I can't change my database structure(I'm using an existing one).Can I use a foreign key ?I mean storing remember me token in another table and using foreign key.

Comment: Can you not add to your existing database using a migration?

Comment: @user1572461 I tried to explain the way you may achieve doing it. But think once more about the cost!